# Select Options: replace text with new value

Tags: html, reactjs, jsx

I feel as though I am very close to a solution for this. I searched for similar questions but I do not believe I have found the answer I am looking for.

What I would like:

I have a select dropdown with long text options, and would like to replace the value from handle change with the first word in the option, and set that as the new button select option.

What I currently have:

I modify the incoming handleChange to the first word, attempt to set it on the select button, and it never happens.

codepen: `https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gdXVJM?editors=1011`

code:

HTML

```
<div id="input"></div>
```

JS

```
    class MyInput extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      buttonStyle: '',
      voiceSelected: ''
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

 handleChange(event) {
    event.persist();
     if (event.target.id === 'voiceSelected') {

      //set the state we're going to use later

      this.setState(() => ({ 'voiceSelected': event.target.value}));

      //Take the first word from the string to make it visable on button

      let totalWords = event.target.value
      var firstWord = totalWords.replace(/ .*/,'');
      console.log(firstWord)
      this.setState(() => ({'buttonStyle': firstWord}));



    } else {
      console.log("Something Went Wrong!")
    }
  }

  render(){
    return  <select 
              id="voiceSelected" 
              value={this.state.buttonStyle} 
              name={this.state.buttonStyle} 
              onChange={(e) => {this.handleChange(e)}}
              >
      <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Choose Voice</option>
      <option value="Ivy">Ivy [English - American]</option>
      <option value="Joanna">Joanna [English - American]</option>
      <option value="Joey">Joey [English - American]</option>
      <option value="Justin">Justin [English - American]</option>
      <option value="Kendra">Kendra [English - American]</option>
      <option value="Kimberly">Kimberly [English - American]</option>
      <option value="Salli">Salli [English - American]</option>
      <option value="Nicole">Nicole [English - Australian]</option>
      <option value="Russell">Russell [English - Australian]</option>
      <option value="Emma">Emma [English - British]</option>
      <option value="Brian">Brian [English - British]</option>
      <option value="Amy">Amy [English - British]</option>
      <option value="Raveena">Raveena [English - Indian]</option>
      <option value="Geraint">Geraint [English - Welsh]</option>
      <option value="Ricardo">Ricardo [Brazilian Portuguese]</option>
      <option value="Vitoria">Vitoria [Brazilian Portuguese]</option>
      <option value="Lotte">Lotte [Dutch]</option>
      <option value="Ruben">Ruben [Dutch]</option>
      <option value="Mathieu">Mathieu [French]</option>
      <option value="Celine">Celine [French]</option>
      <option value="Chantal">Chantal [Canadian French]</option>
      <option value="Marlene">Marlene [German]</option>
      <option value="Dora">Dora [Icelandic]</option>
      <option value="Karl">Karl [Icelandic]</option>
      <option value="Carla">Carla [Italian]</option>
      <option value="Giorgio">Giorgio [Italian]</option>
      <option value="Mizuki">Mizuki [Japanese]</option>
      <option value="Liv">Liv [Norwegian]</option>
      <option value="Maja">Maja [Polish]</option>
      <option value="Jan">Jan [Polish]</option>
      <option value="Ewa">Ewa [Polish]</option>
      <option value="Cristiano">Cristiano [Portuquese]</option>
      <option value="Ines">Ines [Portuquese]</option>
      <option value="Carmen">Carmen [Romanian]</option>
      <option value="Maxim">Maxim [Russian]</option>
      <option value="Tatyana">Tatyana [Russian]</option>
      <option value="Enrique">Enrique [Spanish]</option>
      <option value="Penelope">Penelope [US Spanish]</option>
      <option value="Enrique">Miguel [US Spanish]</option>
      <option value="Conchita">Conchita [Castilian Spanish]</option>
      <option value="Astrid">Astrid [Swedish]</option>
      <option value="Filiz">Filiz [Turkish]</option>
      <option value="Gwyneth">Gwyneth [Welsh]</option>
  </select>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyInput/>, document.getElementById('input'));
```

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is not possible, as the selected value will show what you have inside the `<option></option>`.

Comment: Please show complete component

Comment: So, do you want to change `Ivy [English - American]` to `Ivy` in the option?

Comment: @SakhiMansoor I am not sure what I am missing here that you need to see.

Comment: And yes, @devserkan, that would be ideal :)

Answer (score 0):

`<select>` doesn't have 'value' attribute.  we can get the value of select box by using 'selected' attribute in `<options>`
[Please refer doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select)

Comment: correct, I am just trying anything. I saw there is a name prop but that doesn't work, same with selected? Maybe it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it suits you but if you can keep your options in the state you can somehow manipulate them. But with this method, you are losing the long values when you select an option. Maybe you can improve the logic starting with this answer.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    options: [
      "Ivy [English - American]",
      "Joanna [English - American]",
      "Joey [English - American]",
      "Justin [English - American]"
    ],
    selectedIndex: 0
  };

  handleChange = event => {
    const { selectedIndex, value } = event.target;
    const { options } = this.state;
    var firstWord = value.replace(/ .*/, "");
    const newOptions = Object.assign([], options, {
      [selectedIndex - 1]: firstWord
    });
    this.setState({ options: newOptions, selectedIndex });
  };

  render() {
    const { options } = this.state;
    return (
      <select
        id="voiceSelected"
        value={this.state.options[this.state.selectedIndex - 1]}
        name={this.state.buttonStyle}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
      >
        <option value="">Choose Voice</option>
        {
            options.map( option =>
                <option key={option}>{option}</option>
            )
        }
      </select>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, your answer really got me thinking. Maybe I could reset the options value to their default upon select click. Starting to sound really hacky hahah.

Comment: I edited your example up to this point https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VGywXX?editors=1010 Wondering if you had any ideas on how I can prevent the first load of the menu? The way I wrote it makes it so the menu is rendered twice, and I can not find a reliable answer currently. I thought event.preventDefault might work, but I'm not too sure now.

Comment: I don't know is it a proper way to add event listeners like that but it is not working because of `this` context. You are using a regular function in your callback. Change it to an arrow one like: `addEventListener("click", () => {...`

Comment: changing this to an arrow function makes no difference on my end. It is still loading the menu then loading it again with the next state instead of only loading next state. I was just thinking maybe there is some way to prevent the action after the click until the new state is finished.

Comment: I can't understand your point. Changing it to an arrow function makes it work. When you click the `select` it updates the options state again as you intended. Maybe I understood it wrong but this small change fixes this bug. Other than that I don't get your intention, sorry.

Comment: Try to select 2 menu options consecutively and you'll see what I mean, I think.

Comment: If not, thank you for your help so far. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Though I'm not so experienced I want to help but I don't really understand your problem :) Maybe it is the language since I am not a native English speaker maybe something else, but sincerely I don't understand it.